# Client receiving packet only on close

Tags: c#, sockets, packet

Basically I made two C# applications, a client and a server. The client connects to the server (via sockets), then sends a packet containing some text, and the server should reply.
My problem is: the server sends (or the client receives) the response packet only when it closes (ALT+F4). I'd like some help. I'll copypaste below the source code for both the projects.
Client:

```
public class StateObject
{
    public Socket skt = null;
    public const int BufferSize = 256;
    public byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
}

public class AsynchronousClient
{
    private const int port = 11000;
    private static ManualResetEvent connectDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent sendDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static ManualResetEvent receiveDone =
        new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private static String response = String.Empty;
    public static string command;
    public static Socket client;
    public static void StartClient()
    {
        try
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"));
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
            client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            while (true)
            {
                command = Console.ReadLine();
                if (command == "exit")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Terminating...");
                    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Close();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }
                else
                {
                    Send(client, command + "<EOF>");
                    sendDone.WaitOne();
                    Receive(client);
                    receiveDone.WaitOne();
                    Console.WriteLine("Response received : {0}", ProcessResponse(response));
                    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    client.Close();
                }
                //Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) =>
                //{
                //    Console.WriteLine("Terminating...");
                //    client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                //    client.Close();
                //    Environment.Exit(0);
                //};
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
    static public string ProcessResponse(string pkt)
    {
        string response = null;
        response = pkt.Replace("<EOF>","");
        return response;
    }
    private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            client.EndConnect(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Socket connected to {0}",
                client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
            connectDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.skt = client;
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket client = state.skt;
            int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString();
                }
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
        client.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
    }

    private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
            Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
            sendDone.Set();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static int Main(String[] args)
    {
        StartClient();
        return 0;
    }
```

Server:

```
public class Program
{
    public class StateObject
    {
        public Socket skt = null;
        public const int buffersize = 1024;
        public byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
        public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    }
    public class AsynchronousSocketListener
    {
        public static ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        public AsynchronousSocketListener() { }
        public static Socket handler;
        public static void StartListening()
        {
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
            IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve(Dns.GetHostName());
            IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 11000);

            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);
                while (true)
                {
                    allDone.Reset();
                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection...");
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            allDone.Set();
            Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
            StateObject state = new StateObject();
            state.skt = handler;
            handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.buffersize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
        }
        public static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            String content = String.Empty;
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
            Socket handler = state.skt;
            int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                if (content.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes from socket. \n Data : {1}", content.Length, ProcessResponse(content));
                    Send(handler, content);
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.buffersize, 0,
                    new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                }
            }
        }
        private static void Send(Socket handler, String data)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);
            handler.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), handler);
        }
        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
                Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to client.", bytesSent);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        }
        static public string ProcessResponse(String pkt)
        {
            string response = null;
            response = pkt.Replace("<EOF>", "");
            return response;
        }
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsynchronousSocketListener.StartListening();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your **Client** receive callback:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.skt;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));
            client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
        }
        else
        {
            if (state.sb.Length > 1)
            {
                response = state.sb.ToString();
            }
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

You won't ever drop down into the `else` block unless the socket is explicitly closed (or there is some kind of other error in the connection).  Therefore `receiveDone` never gets set and your main loop is simply stuck waiting for a "response".

If you want to process a "complete message" when it comes in, then check for your `<EOF>` value after you append the current string to your buffer like this:

```
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead));

                // it's not a "response" unless it's terminated with "<EOF>" right?
                response = state.sb.ToString();
                if (response.IndexOf("<EOF>") != -1)
                {
                    state.sb.Clear();
                    receiveDone.Set();
                }
                else
                {
                    client.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
                        new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), state);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (state.sb.Length > 1)
                {
                    response = state.sb.ToString(); // this is a partial response, not terminated with "<EOF>"
                }
                receiveDone.Set();
            }
```

Note that response mechanism being used is extremely limited as it would fail for multiple messages coming in at the same time like: `Hello<EOF> World!<EOF>`  It would treat those two messages as one long message.  (I realize your example is only sending one "message".)

You're almost certainly going to have to deal with that scenario in any real world application that sends "control" messages in addition to "content" messages.  To handle that you'd look for `<EOF>` using IndexOf() and extract the text up to that point and process that "complete message".  Afterwards you'd keep looping as long as `<EOF>` is still found to process the other pending messages.  You'd also have to REMOVE those processed complete messages from the StringBuilder in such a way that any remaining values after the `<EOF>` are left in place so that when partial messages come in the new data can be appended to the existing data.  This is because your data can also be split up when it is sent, resulting in multiple "chunks" of data being received even though it is logically one "complete message" when you sent it.  So one send with `Complete Message<EOF>` could result in one or more receives such as `Comp` followed by `lete Message<EOF>`.  Your code has to be able to deal with these realities of TCP communication...

Comment: Thank you! Really helped. I've just started learning how sockets work (with just 2 weeks of self-taught csharp experience).

Comment: You might like my [Article](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/Visual_Basic.NET/A_11178-A-Peer-To-Peer-LAN-Chat-Application-in-Visual-Basic-Net-using-TcpClient-and-TcpListener.html)...it's in VB.Net, but the concepts still apply.